# Does Gamora have a bounty on her head?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Peter Quill is issued a bounty by Yondu when he flees with the orb. This introduces us to Rocket and Groot with their little HUD tech while on Xandar. Among the other Xandarians they scan during the scene, they do not scan Gamora.

She seems to have everyone against her and when she is in jail Rocket says that she won't last a day due to all the enemies she and Ronan's goons have made.

**Question**: Does Gamora ever have a bounty on her head?

Comment: Does she not? What makes you think she'd doesn't?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage, If she did, would not Rocket have know and tried to get it? All he says was that she has a reputation.

Comment: Maybe the galaxy thought twice about putting a bounty on Thanos' adoptive daughter. Quietly knifing her in a prison could be seen as less likely to bring about retribution.

Answer (score 1):

### Not that we know of.

There is no mention of a bounty on her on the first movie. [You can read the full transcript here](https://subslikescript.com/movie/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy-2015381). The only mention of a bounty is the one mentioned in the question for Quill.

On the second movie ([transcript here](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2)) the only mention of a bounty is for Nebula.

This does not mean Gamora does not have a bounty on her - we do not know her full past, and this might be something that comes up in future movies.

Answer (score -1):

I have a hazy memory of it, but I sure do know that only Quill has a bounty on his head. Gamora, just said she has a reputation (a bad one at that) by following Thanos' orders.

Comment: I’d like to point out that we only see Quill’s bounty and that they don’t say anyone else has one. That doesn’t mean only Quill has one but only Quill is said to have one.

Answer (score -2):

Yes she 100% does, she had since she got sent to the Kyln there was a large bounty placed on her by Thanos so he could get her back. She still has the bounty on her throughout the films but no one dared to mess with the Guardians Of The Galaxy enough to try and get her, since by the end it would end with improsonment or fatal injuries for them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for any of this that you could [edit] in? When did Thanos set the bounty on her?

Comment: That is not Gamora. The bounty is on Nebula. The actual sentence from the transcript is said by Gamora herself and goes: ["She’s worth no more to me than the bounty due for her on Xandar."](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2)